# Flutter Build Failed because of pubsec dependencies (audioplayer)

Tags: android, flutter, avaudioplayer

I was trying to add `audioplayers: ^0.13.2` to the pubsec.yaml file.

At first it was working then after a while when I run the app there's an error in the Build:
`Could not determine the dependencies of task ':audioplayers:compileDebugAidl'.` 
`Failed to find target with hash string 'android-28' in: C:\Users\myRepo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

My pubsec:

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.2
  firebase_database: ^6.0.0
  audioplayers: ^0.7.8
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

Comment: Share your pubspec.yml file here

Comment: Hi already solved the issue. but when i try to add ```firebase_messaging``` still gets the same error.

Comment: try to downgrade firebase_messaging dependencies...

Comment: @RahulKushwaha downgrading didn't work. and it looks like it is a known issue in flutter when using ^7.0.3. I'm using ^8.0.0-dev.14 in my app and it solved the issue